# как создать компонент vue?

Tags: vue.js

Как создать компонент vue, в котором через пропсы можно менять css свойства, как во фреймворках для vue. Например есть компонент Button, ему в пропсах можно указать width='200' и кнопка станет такой же ширины. Здесь вроде бы все просто и понятно, возьми да через реф поменяй свойство style.width, но вот у них это реализовано как то по другому, там свойство style не меняется и мне вот интересно как это реализовано у них. Подумал в сторону изменения css-переменных через js, но может быть есть еще какой то вариант реализации?

Answer (score 0):

Совету читать документацию вдоль и поперек :)

Вот, [в документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) по вашему вопросу найдете кучу информации

```js
// AppButton.vue
export default {
  props: ['width']
}
```

```html
<!-- Home.vue -->
<app-button width="200">Button text</app-button>

<!-- AppButton.vue -->
<button :style="width">
  <slot />
</button>
```